# SQL Query, using MAX() instead of TOP

Tags: sql

I have to take from Table Common_CustomerComments one description with max Priority (max priority is 3) and max InsertDate

I used this query

```
select TOP 1 Description 
from Common_CustomerComments 
WHERE CustomerCode = 1 
  AND Priority > 1 
ORDER BY Priority desc, InsertDate desc
```

but I need create query without 'TOP', Can someone help me create query with MAX() function

I tried this query but i have problem with this:

```
SELECT Description 
FROM Common_CustomerComments 
WHERE CustomerCode = 1 
  and Id IN (SELECT MAX(Priority) 
             FROM Common_CustomerComments pr 
             JOIN (SELECT MAX(InsertDate) as maxdata))
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (TOP is a product specific functionality.)

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Can you elaborate on your logic. The max priority doesn't necessarily match the max insertDate. This is where some sample data and expected result help a lot to explain your problem

Comment: Why you need create query without TOP ? And what problem you have with your second query? Any error or wrong result?

Comment: I need use this query for ms sql and my sql

Comment: cant you try with order by priority deseeding and InsertDate and get first record.

Comment: Cant you have two queries? On MySql you use `LIMIT 1`

Comment: I need 1 query for ms sql and mysql, so without 'top'

Comment: I should take the newest description (last InsertDate) with priority = 3 or if description with priority = 3 doesnt exists I should take the newest with priority = 2

Comment: What MySql version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select cc.Description 
from (select cc.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customercode order by priority desc, insertdate desc) as seqnum
      from Common_CustomerComments
      where CustomerCode = 1 and Priority > 1  
     ) cc
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: row_number only  if you have MySql 8+

Answer (score 0):

In *general*, you can use `subquery` with *correlation* approach :

```
select cc.*
from Common_CustomerComments cc
where id = (select top 1 cc1.id
            from Common_CustomerComments cc1
            where cc1.customercode = cc.customercode 
            order by cc1.priority desc, cc1.insertdate desc
           );
```

However, this assumes id is `PK` (i.e. Primary Key) if so, then the equivalent approach is `LIMIT` clause in *MySQL*

Something like that :

```
 . . .
where id = (select cc1.id
            from Common_CustomerComments cc1
            where cc1.customercode = cc.customercode 
            order by cc1.priority desc, cc1.insertdate desc
            limit 1
            );
```